# Query for retrieving most popular video

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

I have a table that maintains information related to video and their likes.

[image]

So i want to get most liked videoid for that i queried the following way

> select VideoId,count(LikeStatus) from Likes where Status='0' group by VideoId

I get the following output

[image]

works fine but i need this query to be nested query i mean

```
select title,desc from videos where videoID IN (select VideoId,count(LikeStatus) from Likes where Status='0' group by VideoId)
```

I know that sub query must return only one field, so is there any other good method?

Comment: Why do you need the second filed, count(LikeStatus), in sub query? What do you want to do with main query?

Comment: From the main query i need to fetch 20 20 records. i dont want to fetch all records at once. just like limit $start,20 for main query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM   Videos
 INNER
  JOIN (
        SELECT VideoId
             , Count(*) As number_of_likes
        FROM   Likes
        WHERE  Status = '0'
        GROUP
            BY VideoId
       ) As likes
    ON likes.VideoId = Videos.VideoId
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understant well you try to do bellow code (?)

```
SELECT title,desc 
FROM videos V
LEFT JOIN Likes L ON V.id = L.VideoId

WHERE (select count(LikeStatus) from Likes DL where DL.Status='0' AND DL.VideoId = V.id group by DL.VideoId) > 0

GROUP BY V.id

ORDER BY (select count(LikeStatus) from Likes DL where DL.Status='0' AND DL.VideoId = V.id group by DL.VideoId) DESC
```

Am I right?

Comment: Sorry i cant test now as my server is down. will let you know soon after i test